Tasker Bluetooth connection times out
I'm trying to make a Tasker profile/action that automatically connects my Android device to my phone via bluetooth for internet access. I'd like it to be invoked whenever the device is unlocked. The phone is paired via bluetooth and manually connecting works, but when I try running the Bluetooth Connection > Connect action in Tasker via either the MAC address or name, it times out.
17.00.49/LicenseCheckerTasker Checking cached only
17.00.49/LicenseCheckerTasker Is direct and license was validated
17.00.49/LicenseCheckerTasker Cached only: Licensed
17.00.49/Ew add wait type EasyAction1 time 2147483647
17.00.49/Ew add wait type EasyAction1 done
17.00.49/E add wait task
17.02.08/E Error: 1
17.02.08/E Could not perform Bluetooth Connect action. Timed out.

Screenshots:


Are there any known solutions to this, or other steps I should take to troubleshoot?
